# Native SMS app resending sms when I store all sms in its outbox

Tags: android

I'm sending sms from my android application and storing it into phone sms outbox.

When I switch off my phone and switch on than all sms which I've stored into outbox are resent to its corresponding number.

How I can oppose this resending sms?

My sms storing code is:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", "something");

    values.put("subject", "something"); 
    values.put("body", "something");

    values.put("type", "4");
    values.put("status", Common.STATUS_VALUE_DELIVERED_SUCCESS);
    values.put("error_code", Common.ERROR_CODE);
    long milli = getTimeInMillis(mi.Date);
        path = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(path, values);
```

Comment: You cant send SMS once you mobile is switch off

Comment: I'm sending sms when my mobile is switch on.

Comment: how to save text messages in the outbox? show that portion of the code